# Query working in MySQL but trowing error in Oracle can someone please explain. and tell me how to rewrite this same query in oracle to avoid error

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

MySql query which is working fine:

```
select 
    c.hacker_id, h.name, count(c.hacker_id) as c_count
from 
    Hackers H, Challenges C
where 
    H.hacker_id = C.hacker_id
group by
    H.hacker_id,H.name
having 
    c_count = (select max(temp1.cnt)
               from (select count(hacker_id) as cnt
                     from challenges
                     group by hacker_id) temp1)
    or c_count in (select t.cnt
                   from (select count(*) as cnt 
                         from challenges
                         group by hacker_id) t
                   group by t.cnt
                   having count(t.cnt) = 1)
order by 
    c_count DESC, c.hacker_id;
```

Same query is throwing this error in Oracle:

> c_count in (select t.cnt 
>   *  ERROR at line 11:  **ORA-00904**: "C_COUNT": invalid identifier

Comment: You can't use aliases in the `HAVING` clause in Oracle. You need to use `count(c.hacker_id)` instead of `c_count`

Comment: See the second answer in the duplicate for an explanation from the manual

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**over 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: @marc_s Even when I use that join I get the same error

Comment: @Nick count(c.hacker_id) it's trowing group by error

Comment: @Nick I was using H.hacker_Id instead of c.Hacker_id so when I changed group by error was gone. Thank you

Comment: @AmareshKarnan That's good to hear. I'm glad you solved your problem.